# add attribute to input from array; however, using value pair from jsaon

Tags: javascript, json

I'm getting error: setAttribute' on 'Element': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.

I want to add attributes to an input but i'm avoiding repeats:

```
//putHolder.setAttribute("placeholder", "Product Name (required)");
//putHolder.setAttribute("ng-model", "vm.product.productName");
//putHolder.setAttribute("ng-minlength", "4");
//putHolder.setAttribute("ng-maxlength", "12");
//putHolder.removeAttribute("size");
```

I have used the following code but i can't get it right:

```
var putHolder = document.getElementById('CustomerID');
//var result = '{"placeholder":"Product Name (required)","ng-model":"vm.product.productName","ng-minlength":"4", "ng-maxlength":"12"}';
//$.each($.parseJSON(result), function (k, v) {
//        putHolder.setAttribute(k + ' = ' + v);
//    });

//or js  please i prefer javascript

JSON.parse('{"placeholder":"Product Name (required)","ng-model":"vm.product.productName","ng-minlength":"4", "ng-maxlength":"12"}', function(k, v) {
        putHolder.setAttribute(k + ' = ' + v);
    });
```

I've also tried a loop but is just 1 elem like so:

```
var names = ["size", "value"];
for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i = ++i) {
    var cadaUno = names[i];
    putHolder.removeAttribute(cadaUno);
}
```

I hope someone can help thanks.

Comment: Change putHolder.setAttribute(k + ' = ' + v); to putHolder.setAttribute(k , v);

Comment: I'm sorry lid i need the = sign too. and no it didn't work thank though

Comment: element.setAttribute(key,value); https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute that is the proper way to set an attribute. calling setAttribute properly will produce the attribute on the element as you may expect with the "=" sign.  if it does not work, you may have a additional issues with your code.